# ¿Cómo se hacen las comparaciones en ArrayList.indexOf?

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de ver cómo se hacen las comparaciones en ArrayList para encontrar un artículo. Especialmente si hemos almacenado un elemento p1 y que p2 = p1, ¿podemos encontrar su índice? Del mismo modo, si tenemos un elemento p3 que tiene las mismas características que p1.

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 

class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Point(int px, int py) {
        this.x = px;  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
        this.y = py;
     }

    public int getx(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setx(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int gety(){
        return this.y;
    }

    public void sety(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isSameAs(Point p1, Point p2){
        if ((p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y)){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point p1=new Point(1,2);
        Point p2=p1;
        Point p3=new Point(1,2);

        ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(p1);
        System.out.println(list.indexOf(p2));
        System.out.println(list.indexOf(p3));
    }

}
```

Sin embargo me retorno que p3 no está en la lista mientras que p2 está :

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java Point
0
-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactamente, p3 no esta en la lista. Si no lo agregaste nunca a la lista.

Veamos que paso ahí.

```
Point p1=new Point(1,2);
```

Esto es una instancia del objeto `Point` con los valores 1 y 2

```
Point p2=p1;
```

Esto es una variable (p2) que apunta a la misma instancia que p1 del objeto `Point`.

```
Point p3=new Point(1,2);
```

Esto, es otra instancia del objeto `Point`, que de casualidad tiene los mismos valores. Pero a fines del sistema, es otro objeto diferente.

Y cuando haces esto:

```
System.out.println(list.indexOf(p2));
System.out.println(list.indexOf(p3));
```

Le estas pidiendo a la lista que busque una instancia de ese objeto. Por instancia, el sistema busca no el contenido, si no la posición de memoria que tiene ese mismo objeto, o sea que apunten al mismo lugar.

Como p1 y p2 apuntan al mismo lugar, entonces lo encuentra, porque agregaste p1 a la lista.

Sin embargo, p3 no esta en la lista. En ningún caso, el indexOf busca por contenido. Siempre busca por que la instancia del objeto sea la misma.

Comment: *Siempre busca por que el la instancia del objeto sea la misma.* No, busca por que *equals()* devuelva *true*. Por supuesto, como el OP no lo implementa, *equals()* usa la implementación por defecto que acaba siendo *==*.

Comment: Equals que busca? instancia o datos?

Comment: La implementación por defecto (de *Object*) es simplemente *this == obj;*, así que el resultado solo es *true* si se compara con la misma instancia. Pero se puede reimplementar para que haga las comparaciones que se quiera.

Comment: Ah si si.. es mas.. fijate que la clase tiene un isSame.. Pero no lo usa para comparar. Si hubiera usado eso para comparar los objetos, le hubiera dado que todos eran el mismo...

Comment: Me parece que no entiendes lo que digo, he escrito mi propia respuesta.

Comment: @gbianchi indexOf usa internamente equals(). equals, a menos que lo sobreescribas, usa `==` para comparar. OP debería implementar equals (y hashCode, siempre es bueno implementar ambos métodos) para que indexOf encuentre correctamente los elementos iguales, sean o no el mismo

Comment: @PabloLozano totalmente de acuerdo. Igual yo conteste porque no le daba que era el mismo, que fue lo que pregunto.

Comment: @PabloLozano igual es importante resaltar que instancia es distinta de datos.. eso queda siempre flotando y despues tenes leaks de memoria por ese motivo

Answer (score 2):

Invocando al método *equals(Object)*. De hecho, [de la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)<sup>1</sup>:

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

Si pasas *null* te devolverá la posición del primer elemento *null*, si pasas no *null* te devolverá la posición del primer elemento tal que *parametro.equals(elemento)*.

La cuestión es que como no implementas *equals*, la implementación que se usa es la implementación por defecto, y esa implementación solo comprueba que los dos objetos sean la misma instancia. Si quieres hacer una comparación, deberás implementar *equals(Object)* en tu clase con la lógica que necesites; p. ej:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
       return false;
    }
    if (!obj instanceof Point) {
       return false;
    }
    Point p1 = (Point) obj;
    return this.x == p1.x && this.y == p1.y;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>La documentación del API de Java es realmente informativa y si te acostumbras a consultarla resolverás por tí mismo muchas dudas.

Comment: Ésta es la respuesta correcta