# ¿Qué pasa si pregunto si una lista contiene (nulo)?

Tags: java

Tengo que escribir una clase que representa una línea discontinua, es decir, una serie de puntos (la clase `Point` está disponible [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255280/c%C3%B3mo-se-hacen-las-comparaciones-en-arraylist-indexof)). La línea quebrada tendrá un número máximo de puntos definidos en la creación, pero puede variar de uno instancia a otro. He creado un método `contains` que indique si un argumento pasado está contenido en la línea discontinua.

¿Qué sucede si se pasa null como argumento para el método `contains`?
? ¿Y si hiciéramos un `add(null)` antes? Parece que hay una cosa que ver con 
`Objects.requireNonNull (o)`.

```
class LigneBrisee{

    private int maxNumber;
    private ArrayList<Point> pointsList;

    // Ecrire le constructeur d’une ligne brisee.
    public LigneBrisee(int maxNumber){
        this.maxNumber = maxNumber;
    }

    // Ecrire une methode add ajoutant un point a la ligne brisee.
    public void add(Point point)    {
        if (this.pointsList == null) {
            this.pointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();
        }
        else if(pointsList.size() > this.maxNumber){
            System.out.println("The list is full");
        }
        else {
            this.pointsList.add(point);
        }
    }

    // Ecrire une methode pointCapacity() et nbPoints() indiquant la capacite de la ligne brisee et le nombre de points actuellement sur la ligne.
    public int pointCapacity(){
        return maxNumber;
    }

    public int nbPoints(){
        return this.pointsList.size();
    }

    // Ecrire une methode contains indiquant si un point passe en argument est contenu dans la ligne brisee. Vous utiliserez pour cela une boucle for each et non une boucle classique.
    public boolean contains(Point p){
        for (Point point : this.pointsList){
            if point == p{
                return true;
            }
        }  
        return false;
    }
}
```

## Actualización

Probé el código con :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    LigneBrisee l = new LigneBrisee(5);
    l.contains(null);
}
```

Y me devuelve:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java Point
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at LigneBrisee.contains(Point.java:77)
        at Point.main(Point.java:38)
```

Mientras que `l.add(null)` no me devuelve nada.

Comment: Con toda la buena onda te pregunto: ¿Probaste ejecutar lo que nos preguntas? Y si lo hiciste, cuál fue el resultado?

Comment: O puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-): contains(null) devolverá true si algún elemento es null.

Comment: Por otro lado, que significado tiene en tu abstracción de una linea discontinua un punto null? Representa algo?

Comment: por esto es que el champu trae instrucciones!

Comment: @Juan No, no representa nada. Solo es para probar las estructuras de tabla de Java

Comment: @PabloLozano Muchas gracias para la referencia. Sin embargo me devuelva una error.

Comment: @Alfabravo Me disculpe. Debería haberlo añadido antes. El resultado fue NullPointerException